# Problema con Codeigniter 4 y Cors

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, cors

Buen día, estoy armando un sistema en Codeigniter 4 donde hago llamadas con ajax a los controladores para cargar información en ventanas popups. Funcionaba todo bien hasta que de golpe me empezó a dar error entiendo con algo relacionado a strict-origin-when-cross-origin ,  probé de todo pero no encuentro la solución,

en un momento agregué estas cabeceras a los controladores:

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');

Esto funcionó por unos días pero ahora me vuelvo a encontrar con el mismo error...
(Otro dato que también me confunde es por que en la misma vista tengo otras llamadas por ajax a otros controladores y en ese caso funciona sin problemas, las comparo y son similares solo cambia el nombre del controlador con el que se conecta)

Alguien me podrá orientar cual puede ser el problema? Dese ya muchas gracias!

https://aysys2.com.ar/Captura.PNG

https://aysys2.com.ar/Captura2.PNG

Comment: Un error 500 significa un problema en backend, no en el navegador

Comment: Me huele a que tienes un problema con los permisos para acceder a los archivos, de casualidad no has modificado alguno?

Comment: No creo que sea eso porque ese mismo controlador tiene otras funciones que puedo llamar sin problema.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando configuras CSRF protection necesitas enviar un campo con el token en el formulario y lo puedes hacer de la siguiente forma:

```
<input type="hidden" name="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>" value="<?php echo csrf_hash(); ?>" />
```

> Los tokens pueden regenerarse en cada envío (predeterminado) o
> mantenerse iguales durante la vida de la cookie CSRF. La regeneración
> predeterminada de tokens proporciona una seguridad más estricta, pero
> puede resultar en problemas de usabilidad cuando otros tokens se
> vuelven inválidos (navegación hacia atrás / adelante, múltiples
> pestañas / ventanas, acciones asincrónicas, etc.).

Al hacer peticiones AJAX usa el mismo token por lo cual marca `500 internal server error`.

Para corregir ese error cambia el valor de regeneración del token:

1. Ve al archivo `app/Config/Security.php`
2. Busca la configuración `public $regenerate  = true;`
3. Cámbiala a `public $regenerate = false;`

[Cross-site request forgery (CSRF) - Security CodeIngiter 4](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf)